# Burgers equation solution rapidly increasing

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, pde

I got a problem implementing a simple subroutine for solving the Burgers 
equation:

[image]

Boundary condition x=[0,5] t=[0,1]

The problem is that the code well predicts all the values of the resulting vector in function `f(x,U(time,x))` if I change the time step, the size of domain and so on... the last 4 points of the vector (a columns of a matrix U) are out of range of the normal solution (generally rapidly increasing)

Here is the code (module subroutines and simple main):

```
MODULE PARAM 
        IMPLICIT NONE 
        INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: SP = KIND(1.0)
        INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: DP = KIND(1.D0)
      END MODULE 
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      MODULE BURGER_2
       USE PARAM 
       IMPLICIT NONE

       REAL(DP), PARAMETER   :: x0=0. , xF= 5.
       REAL(DP), PARAMETER   :: t0=0. , tF= 1.0
       REAL(DP), PARAMETER   :: dx=0.01, dt=0.1
       INTEGER , PARAMETER   :: N= CEILING((xF-x0)/dx)
       INTEGER , PARAMETER   :: M= CEILING((tF-t0)/dt)
       REAL(DP), PARAMETER   :: nu = 1D-4 
       REAL(DP), PARAMETER   :: pi=3.14159265358979323846 


      CONTAINS 
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
         SUBROUTINE BURGER_EXPLICIT (x,t,u) 
           USE PARAM 
           REAL(DP), DIMENSION(N+1)     :: x
           REAL(DP), DIMENSION(M+1)     :: t
           REAL(DP), DIMENSION(N+1,M+1) :: U
           REAL(DP)   :: r,k
           INTEGER    :: i,j,stat



           x(1:N+1)       = (/ ( x0+dx*(i-1) , i=1,N+1 ) /)       
           t(1:M+1)       = (/ (t0+ dt*(j-1) , j=1,M+1 ) /)
           U(1:N+1,1:M+1) = RESHAPE((/(((sin(2*pi*(i-1)/N)), i=1,N+1), j=1,M+1)/),(/N+1,M+1/)) 

           U(1,:)   = x0
           U(N+1,:) = xF

           U(:,1)   = t0
           U(:,M+1) = tF



           r = nu*DT/DX**2
           k = DT/(2*DX)

           DO J=2,M
            DO I=2,N
              U(i,j+1) = r*u(i+1,j)+(1-2*r)*u(i,j)+r*u(i-1,j) - k*u(i,j)*(u(i+1,j)-u(i-1,j))
            END DO
           END DO 

           !DO j=1,M+1  
           OPEN(10,file='bur1.dat',STATUS='UNKNOWN',IOSTAT=stat)
            IF (STAT .NE. 0) THEN 
             WRITE(6,FMT='(A)')'Error opening File ''bur1.dat'' (EXIT1)'
             STOP 
            ELSE     
              WRITE(10,FMT='(2F20.5)') (x(i), u(i,9), i=1,N)        !((u(i,j) , i=1,N+1), J=1,M+1)
              !WRITE(10,*)
              !WRITE(10,FMT='(2F20.5)') (x(i), u(i,2), i=1,N)        !((u(i,j) , i=1,N+1), J=1,M+1)
              WRITE(6,'(50("-"))') 
           !END DO 
            END IF

           RETURN   
         END SUBROUTINE 


!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
!-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      END MODULE
```

the main program is :

```
  PROGRAM main 
  USE BURGER_2
  IMPLICIT NONE 

  REAL(DP) , DIMENSION (N+1) :: xx
  REAL(DP) , DIMENSION (M+1) :: tt
  REAL(DP) , DIMENSION (n+1,M+1) :: UU

  CALL burger_EXPLICIT(xx,tt,UU)


  STOP 
  END
```

I want obtain a matrix (write into a file) for plotting a 3d surface with gnuplot .. but I don't know the right way for write these data

here for exemple the vector that the program wrote for **u(i,9) i=1,N+1**

```
   0.00000             0.00000
         0.01000             0.00637
         0.02000             0.01275
         0.03000             0.01912
         0.04000             0.02550
         0.05000             0.03187
         0.06000             0.03825
         0.07000             0.04462
         0.08000             0.05099
         0.09000             0.05736
         0.10000             0.06374
         0.11000             0.07011
         0.12000             0.07648
         0.13000             0.08285
         0.14000             0.08921
         0.15000             0.09558
         0.16000             0.10195
         0.17000             0.10831
         0.18000             0.11467
         0.19000             0.12104
         0.20000             0.12740
         0.21000             0.13375
         0.22000             0.14011
         0.23000             0.14647
         0.24000             0.15282
         0.25000             0.15917
         0.26000             0.16552
         0.27000             0.17187
         0.28000             0.17822
         0.29000             0.18456
         0.30000             0.19090
         0.31000             0.19724
         0.32000             0.20358
         0.33000             0.20991
         0.34000             0.21624
         0.35000             0.22257
         0.36000             0.22890
         0.37000             0.23522
         0.38000             0.24154
         0.39000             0.24786
         0.40000             0.25417
         0.41000             0.26049
         0.42000             0.26679
         0.43000             0.27310
         0.44000             0.27940
         0.45000             0.28570
         0.46000             0.29199
         0.47000             0.29828
         0.48000             0.30457
         0.49000             0.31085
         0.50000             0.31713
         0.51000             0.32340
         0.52000             0.32967
         0.53000             0.33594
         0.54000             0.34220
         0.55000             0.34846
         0.56000             0.35471
         0.57000             0.36095
         0.58000             0.36720
         0.59000             0.37344
         0.60000             0.37967
         0.61000             0.38590
         0.62000             0.39212
         0.63000             0.39833
         0.64000             0.40455
         0.65000             0.41075
         0.66000             0.41695
         0.67000             0.42315
         0.68000             0.42934
         0.69000             0.43552
         0.70000             0.44169
         0.71000             0.44786
         0.72000             0.45403
         0.73000             0.46018
         0.74000             0.46634
         0.75000             0.47248
         0.76000             0.47862
         0.77000             0.48475
         0.78000             0.49087
         0.79000             0.49698
         0.80000             0.50309
         0.81000             0.50919
         0.82000             0.51528
         0.83000             0.52137
         0.84000             0.52745
         0.85000             0.53351
         0.86000             0.53957
         0.87000             0.54563
         0.88000             0.55167
         0.89000             0.55770
         0.90000             0.56373
         0.91000             0.56975
         0.92000             0.57575
         0.93000             0.58175
         0.94000             0.58774
         0.95000             0.59372
         0.96000             0.59969
         0.97000             0.60565
         0.98000             0.61159
         0.99000             0.61753
         1.00000             0.62346
         1.01000             0.62937
         1.02000             0.63528
         1.03000             0.64117
         1.04000             0.64706
         1.05000             0.65293
         1.06000             0.65878
         1.07000             0.66463
         1.08000             0.67047
         1.09000             0.67629
         1.10000             0.68210
         1.11000             0.68789
         1.12000             0.69367
         1.13000             0.69944
         1.14000             0.70520
         1.15000             0.71094
         1.16000             0.71667
         1.17000             0.72238
         1.18000             0.72808
         1.19000             0.73376
         1.20000             0.73943
         1.21000             0.74508
         1.22000             0.75072
         1.23000             0.75634
         1.24000             0.76194
         1.25000             0.76752
         1.26000             0.77309
         1.27000             0.77864
         1.28000             0.78418
         1.29000             0.78969
         1.30000             0.79519
         1.31000             0.80067
         1.32000             0.80613
         1.33000             0.81157
         1.34000             0.81699
         1.35000             0.82238
         1.36000             0.82776
         1.37000             0.83312
         1.38000             0.83845
         1.39000             0.84377
         1.40000             0.84906
         1.41000             0.85432
         1.42000             0.85957
         1.43000             0.86479
         1.44000             0.86998
         1.45000             0.87515
         1.46000             0.88030
         1.47000             0.88542
         1.48000             0.89051
         1.49000             0.89558
         1.50000             0.90062
         1.51000             0.90563
         1.52000             0.91061
         1.53000             0.91556
         1.54000             0.92048
         1.55000             0.92537
         1.56000             0.93023
         1.57000             0.93506
         1.58000             0.93986
         1.59000             0.94462
         1.60000             0.94935
         1.61000             0.95404
         1.62000             0.95870
         1.63000             0.96332
         1.64000             0.96790
         1.65000             0.97244
         1.66000             0.97695
         1.67000             0.98141
         1.68000             0.98583
         1.69000             0.99020
         1.70000             0.99453
         1.71000             0.99882
         1.72000             1.00305
         1.73000             1.00724
         1.74000             1.01137
         1.75000             1.01545
         1.76000             1.01948
         1.77000             1.02344
         1.78000             1.02734
         1.79000             1.03118
         1.80000             1.03495
         1.81000             1.03864
         1.82000             1.04226
         1.83000             1.04580
         1.84000             1.04925
         1.85000             1.05261
         1.86000             1.05588
         1.87000             1.05903
         1.88000             1.06208
         1.89000             1.06501
         1.90000             1.06780
         1.91000             1.07046
         1.92000             1.07296
         1.93000             1.07531
         1.94000             1.07747
         1.95000             1.07945
         1.96000             1.08122
         1.97000             1.08276
         1.98000             1.08407
         1.99000             1.08511
         2.00000             1.08586
         2.01000             1.08631
         2.02000             1.08643
         2.03000             1.08618
         2.04000             1.08554
         2.05000             1.08448
         2.06000             1.08297
         2.07000             1.08096
         2.08000             1.07843
         2.09000             1.07532
         2.10000             1.07161
         2.11000             1.06725
         2.12000             1.06219
         2.13000             1.05639
         2.14000             1.04980
         2.15000             1.04237
         2.16000             1.03405
         2.17000             1.02479
         2.18000             1.01454
         2.19000             1.00325
         2.20000             0.99087
         2.21000             0.97735
         2.22000             0.96264
         2.23000             0.94670
         2.24000             0.92948
         2.25000             0.91095
         2.26000             0.89106
         2.27000             0.86979
         2.28000             0.84710
         2.29000             0.82298
         2.30000             0.79740
         2.31000             0.77037
         2.32000             0.74187
         2.33000             0.71191
         2.34000             0.68050
         2.35000             0.64766
         2.36000             0.61343
         2.37000             0.57783
         2.38000             0.54092
         2.39000             0.50275
         2.40000             0.46338
         2.41000             0.42289
         2.42000             0.38134
         2.43000             0.33884
         2.44000             0.29548
         2.45000             0.25135
         2.46000             0.20656
         2.47000             0.16123
         2.48000             0.11548
         2.49000             0.06941
         2.50000             0.02316
         2.51000            -0.02316
         2.52000            -0.06941
         2.53000            -0.11548
         2.54000            -0.16123
         2.55000            -0.20656
         2.56000            -0.25135
         2.57000            -0.29548
         2.58000            -0.33884
         2.59000            -0.38134
         2.60000            -0.42289
         2.61000            -0.46338
         2.62000            -0.50275
         2.63000            -0.54092
         2.64000            -0.57784
         2.65000            -0.61343
         2.66000            -0.64767
         2.67000            -0.68050
         2.68000            -0.71191
         2.69000            -0.74187
         2.70000            -0.77037
         2.71000            -0.79740
         2.72000            -0.82298
         2.73000            -0.84710
         2.74000            -0.86979
         2.75000            -0.89106
         2.76000            -0.91095
         2.77000            -0.92948
         2.78000            -0.94670
         2.79000            -0.96264
         2.80000            -0.97735
         2.81000            -0.99087
         2.82000            -1.00325
         2.83000            -1.01454
         2.84000            -1.02479
         2.85000            -1.03405
         2.86000            -1.04237
         2.87000            -1.04980
         2.88000            -1.05639
         2.89000            -1.06219
         2.90000            -1.06725
         2.91000            -1.07161
         2.92000            -1.07532
         2.93000            -1.07843
         2.94000            -1.08096
         2.95000            -1.08297
         2.96000            -1.08448
         2.97000            -1.08554
         2.98000            -1.08618
         2.99000            -1.08643
         3.00000            -1.08631
         3.01000            -1.08586
         3.02000            -1.08511
         3.03000            -1.08407
         3.04000            -1.08276
         3.05000            -1.08122
         3.06000            -1.07945
         3.07000            -1.07747
         3.08000            -1.07531
         3.09000            -1.07296
         3.10000            -1.07046
         3.11000            -1.06780
         3.12000            -1.06501
         3.13000            -1.06208
         3.14000            -1.05903
         3.15000            -1.05588
         3.16000            -1.05261
         3.17000            -1.04925
         3.18000            -1.04580
         3.19000            -1.04226
         3.20000            -1.03864
         3.21000            -1.03495
         3.22000            -1.03118
         3.23000            -1.02734
         3.24000            -1.02344
         3.25000            -1.01948
         3.26000            -1.01545
         3.27000            -1.01137
         3.28000            -1.00724
         3.29000            -1.00305
         3.30000            -0.99882
         3.31000            -0.99453
         3.32000            -0.99020
         3.33000            -0.98583
         3.34000            -0.98141
         3.35000            -0.97695
         3.36000            -0.97244
         3.37000            -0.96790
         3.38000            -0.96332
         3.39000            -0.95870
         3.40000            -0.95404
         3.41000            -0.94935
         3.42000            -0.94462
         3.43000            -0.93986
         3.44000            -0.93506
         3.45000            -0.93023
         3.46000            -0.92537
         3.47000            -0.92048
         3.48000            -0.91556
         3.49000            -0.91061
         3.50000            -0.90563
         3.51000            -0.90062
         3.52000            -0.89558
         3.53000            -0.89051
         3.54000            -0.88542
         3.55000            -0.88030
         3.56000            -0.87515
         3.57000            -0.86998
         3.58000            -0.86479
         3.59000            -0.85957
         3.60000            -0.85432
         3.61000            -0.84906
         3.62000            -0.84377
         3.63000            -0.83845
         3.64000            -0.83312
         3.65000            -0.82776
         3.66000            -0.82238
         3.67000            -0.81699
         3.68000            -0.81157
         3.69000            -0.80613
         3.70000            -0.80067
         3.71000            -0.79519
         3.72000            -0.78969
         3.73000            -0.78418
         3.74000            -0.77864
         3.75000            -0.77309
         3.76000            -0.76752
         3.77000            -0.76194
         3.78000            -0.75634
         3.79000            -0.75072
         3.80000            -0.74508
         3.81000            -0.73943
         3.82000            -0.73376
         3.83000            -0.72808
         3.84000            -0.72238
         3.85000            -0.71667
         3.86000            -0.71094
         3.87000            -0.70520
         3.88000            -0.69944
         3.89000            -0.69367
         3.90000            -0.68789
         3.91000            -0.68210
         3.92000            -0.67629
         3.93000            -0.67047
         3.94000            -0.66463
         3.95000            -0.65878
         3.96000            -0.65293
         3.97000            -0.64706
         3.98000            -0.64117
         3.99000            -0.63528
         4.00000            -0.62937
         4.01000            -0.62346
         4.02000            -0.61753
         4.03000            -0.61159
         4.04000            -0.60565
         4.05000            -0.59969
         4.06000            -0.59372
         4.07000            -0.58774
         4.08000            -0.58175
         4.09000            -0.57575
         4.10000            -0.56975
         4.11000            -0.56373
         4.12000            -0.55770
         4.13000            -0.55167
         4.14000            -0.54563
         4.15000            -0.53957
         4.16000            -0.53351
         4.17000            -0.52745
         4.18000            -0.52137
         4.19000            -0.51528
         4.20000            -0.50919
         4.21000            -0.50309
         4.22000            -0.49698
         4.23000            -0.49087
         4.24000            -0.48475
         4.25000            -0.47862
         4.26000            -0.47248
         4.27000            -0.46634
         4.28000            -0.46018
         4.29000            -0.45403
         4.30000            -0.44786
         4.31000            -0.44169
         4.32000            -0.43552
         4.33000            -0.42934
         4.34000            -0.42315
         4.35000            -0.41695
         4.36000            -0.41075
         4.37000            -0.40455
         4.38000            -0.39833
         4.39000            -0.39212
         4.40000            -0.38590
         4.41000            -0.37967
         4.42000            -0.37344
         4.43000            -0.36720
         4.44000            -0.36095
         4.45000            -0.35471
         4.46000            -0.34846
         4.47000            -0.34220
         4.48000            -0.33594
         4.49000            -0.32967
         4.50000            -0.32340
         4.51000            -0.31713
         4.52000            -0.31085
         4.53000            -0.30457
         4.54000            -0.29828
         4.55000            -0.29199
         4.56000            -0.28570
         4.57000            -0.27940
         4.58000            -0.27310
         4.59000            -0.26679
         4.60000            -0.26049
         4.61000            -0.25417
         4.62000            -0.24786
         4.63000            -0.24154
         4.64000            -0.23522
         4.65000            -0.22890
         4.66000            -0.22257
         4.67000            -0.21624
         4.68000            -0.20991
         4.69000            -0.20358
         4.70000            -0.19724
         4.71000            -0.19090
         4.72000            -0.18456
         4.73000            -0.17822
         4.74000            -0.17187
         4.75000            -0.16552
         4.76000            -0.15917
         4.77000            -0.15282
         4.78000            -0.14647
         4.79000            -0.14011
         4.80000            -0.13375
         4.81000            -0.12740
         4.82000            -0.12104
         4.83000            -0.11467
         4.84000            -0.10831
         4.85000            -0.10195
         4.86000            -0.09558
         4.87000            -0.08921
         4.88000            -0.08285
         4.89000            -0.07648
         4.90000            -0.07011
         4.91000            -0.06374
         4.92000            -0.05736
         4.93000            -0.05099
         4.94000            -0.04068
         4.95000            -0.21859
         4.96000    -539175687.87944
         4.97000********************
         4.98000********************
         4.99000********************
         5.00000********************
         5.01000             5.00000
```

have a look to the last 6 point

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the [tour]. I do not understand your problem, please show use examples which show the problem, see [ask]. Be sure the code you show is complete, currently there is no main program there, se [mcve].

Comment: *"if I change the time step, the size of domain and so on"* How exactly do you change them? How did the solution behave before you changed them? Did it also blow up? Which numerical method do you use? Note there is a specialized site for Scientific computing http://scicomp.stackexchange.com . But do not open a question there if you already have one here, you would have to delete this one.

Comment: I'm sorry .. I'm have not well explained ! the solution is always bad (also if a try to modify the time step , the DX and the domain dimension) the last 4/5 point in the resulting vector * are unresonable out of range ! *(the vector U(i,N) where N is a number of time step)  please try yourself the code !

Comment: Please do not put spaces before ! before ? or before a full stop at the end of a sentence. It looks terrible and is hard to read. I am pretty sure Italian uses the same conventions.

Comment: I cannot try the code, because the code is not complete. Anyway, please document what is wrong, show some pictures or some numbers, you cannot expect that we will start debug your code without enough information from you. And don't forget to explain what the code does Which numerical methods it uses. We can't guess that from the code, you have to explain that.

Comment: `PROGRAM main 
       USE BURGER_2
       IMPLICIT NONE 

       REAL(DP) , DIMENSION (N+1) :: xx
       REAL(DP) , DIMENSION (M+1) :: tt
       REAL(DP) , DIMENSION (n+1,M+1) :: UU
      
       CALL burger_EXPLICIT(xx,tt,UU)

        
       STOP 
      END
`

Comment: this is the main ! I don't know why the code appears in this way

Comment: You cannot put it here in the comments, you must [edit] the question. We need much more than just the code.

Comment: It seems your outer `j` loop should start at `1`  , and its unclear why you fully populate `u` for all `j` (time).  Also be aware you have a forward marching scheme so your condition at `j=M+1` will not be used. None of these things necessarily cause a problem except it makes me wonder if you understand the algorithm.

Comment: @agentp could you explain better ?

Comment: maybe best if you describe the problem, give the equation and boundary conditions (edit the text of the question). I'm guessing what you are doing from the code.

Comment: @agentp ok done !!

Comment: whats the `sin(2 pi..)` for in the code? and what is the assignement `U(:,M+1) = tF` for ?

Comment: Did you check the CFL condition? See [Playing with Burgers's equation](https://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/57/62/48/PDF/burgers.pdf) for instance.

Comment: @agentp sin(2*pi*(i-1)/N) is just a initialization value for the matrix, the condition U(:,M+1) is the Dirichlet condition for final time .. is that's wrong ?

Comment: i've tried to take some hint here http://hmf.enseeiht.fr/travaux/CD0001/travaux/optmfn/hi/01pa/hyb41/reportbid.htm#explicit

Comment: what is wrong is you are using a forward marching scheme and so there can be no boundary condition prescribed at the end time. It is additionally just weird that you have `u= time value` on one edge and `u = position value` on  another.

Comment: youre right !!! i've left this conditions and now the program works better! could you help me about how to write a matrix for plotting a continuous surface 3D plot ?

Comment: Cross-posting -- https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27897/fortran-burgers-equation-solution-problem -- makes a lot of SOers cross.